# MPI calls as OpenMP thread calls?

Tags: multithreading, compilation, multiprocessing, fortran

There is a program in Fortran (OpenMolcas) parallelized using MPI calls and Global Arrays. The problem is, the overhead makes the parallelism effectively non-efficient.
My idea: use one main "MPI" process and call OMP threads instead of MPI calls. I.e. run the code as single-process multi-thread job. Is there a way to instruct a compiler to automatically spawn threads instead of spawning MPI subprocesses?

Also, it already can run in a single-process multi-thread mode, but the threads are used only by the linear algebra calls, which are yet again inefficient in multi-threaded mode (have no idea why).

Tried nothing as of yet (except for performance testing, which resulted in sticking to a single-threaded use), as googling the problem did not bring me any answer.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. This does not sound like a fruitful direction. Whatever you will do, you should certainly first identify where exactly does the inefficiency come from. Measure, profile, test. If the threads are currently only used in a few subroutines, threading the whole program will be a lot of work. And MPI is normally not a source of big inefficiency by itself. In practice, I often get better results with MPI only rather than with OpenMP only for my code.

Comment: Processes and threads are different things. You can't just magically replace one with the other. It will require potentially extensive coding effort.